# Query to Find the "Balance Amount after each Payment of corresponding Bill" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
PaymentID  SupplyInvoiceID   Date     TotalBill   BillPaidAmount    Remaining Bill

1           1              05-04-2018   2,10,000    20,000             1,90,000
2           1              10-05-2018   2,10,000    60,000             1,30,000
3           1              13-06-2018   2,10,000    1,30,000           0 
4           2              10-05-2018   80,000      40,000             40,000
5           2              13-06-2018   80,000      20,000             20,000
6           2              13-06-2018   80,000      20,000             0
```

The payment of each Bill is paid in installments in different dates as shown above. How to find the remaining Bill amount each time when the partial payment of each bill is made?

I used the following Query:

```
SELECT siph.SupplyPaymentID,si.SupplyInvoiceID, 
       siph.DateOfPayment,si.TotalBill, siph.BillPaidAmount,
       si.TotalBill - SUM(siph.BillPaidAmount) over(order by siph.SupplyPaymentID asc) as RemainingBillAmount,
       siph.PaymentMode 
from SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph inner join 
     SupplyInvoice si 
     on siph.SupplyInvoiceID = si.SupplyInvoiceID
```

But it works fine for only bill payments of 1st SupplyInvoiceID. As i enter the bill payments of 2nd and onward SupplyInvoiceID, i gets the wrong result as follows:

```
 PaymentID  SupplyInvoiceID   Date     TotalBill   BillPaidAmount    Remaining Bill

    1           1              05-04-2018   2,10,000    20,000             1,90,000
    2           1              10-05-2018   2,10,000    60,000             1,30,000
    3           1              13-06-2018   2,10,000    1,30,000           0 
    4           2              10-05-2018   80,000      40,000             -1,70,000
    5           2              13-06-2018   80,000      20,000             -1,90,000  
    6           2              15-06-2018   80,000      20,000             -2,10,000
```

..please help to find the correct result as tabulated at the first para of the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `PARTITION BY` clause to your `sum() over ()` to make it a cumulative sum for each Invoice ID.

Add this to your `RemainingBillAmount` column:

```
... - SUM(...) over (partition by si.SupplyInvoiceID ...)
```

Entire query:

```
SELECT siph.SupplyPaymentID,si.SupplyInvoiceID, 
       siph.DateOfPayment,si.TotalBill, siph.BillPaidAmount,
       si.TotalBill - SUM(siph.BillPaidAmount) over(partition by si.SupplyInvoiceID order by siph.SupplyPaymentID asc) as RemainingBillAmount,
       siph.PaymentMode 
from SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph inner join 
     SupplyInvoice si 
     on siph.SupplyInvoiceID = si.SupplyInvoiceID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear..i got the required results.